# Random.nextInt seems wrong from a book

Tags: java

It's a block of code for random verification code in a Servlet book.
the underlined part must be a number of 30+?
but the intention is one of those chars above
[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLnZJ.jpg)

`NextInt` method only has one parameter which is the max number (exclusive)?

So is it a mistake in the book?

Comment: The code randomly selects and index in the array and then retrieves character at that index in the `CHARS` array

Comment: It was silly of me, I didn't realize it's an index of the array  thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nextInt(int)` returns a [pseudo]random number between `0` and the parameter passed to it, exclusive. Thus, if you pass a length of an array, you'd get a random valid index from the array, which you can then use to pick a random element from it, as this code does.

Comment: What about the core question of the thread: "*So is it a mistake in the book?*" - can you explicitly answer it?

Comment: @Zabuza The snippet OP included says nothing about the requirement of "30+". Unfortunately, I can't address this since I don't see the source material that caused OP's misunderstanding.